# What regular expression would I use to grab a certain part of this link?

Tags: javascript

https://www.twitch.tv/averagepothead/clip/TiredRoughElkSquadGoals

I would like to use a regular expression to specifically grab everything after /clip/, aka the five random words that denotes the clip "id". I've been looking up other examples on here, but unfortunately when I write my own expressions based on that I don't get it exactly right... if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction that would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression? `"https://www.twitch.tv/averagepothead/clip/TiredRoughElkSquadGoals".split("/clip/")[1];` should work just fine.

Comment: You are completely correct... this completely slipped my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex? Arguably wrong tool for the job

```
const [dontcare, words] = url.split('clip/');
```

To show what I mean, here's a quick-and-dirty regex version:

```
const match = url.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\/\.:]+clip\/(\w+)/);
const words = match && match[1];
```

That regex is pretty gnarly for such a basic task. You could make it shorter:

```
/.*clip\/(\w+)/
```

at the cost of making it even slower than it already is. Regexes are great for stuff that can't be represented simply as a quick string operation, but are more trouble than they're worth for something like this.

Comment: except `/clips\//` is a regex